# Create new product with woocommerce REST API with javascript (clientside)?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, rest, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I try to create a new product in Woocommerce with its API in javascript (clientside)?

endpoint:

```
https://localhost/wpShop/wc-api/v2/products?consumer_key=ck_1111111111122123&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1458225139&oauth_nonce=nVq4rX&consumer_secret=cs_232332322233232&oauth_signature=kzoVx+VYSWlLbRpi3f8222222=
```

With a `GET` I get all products from Woocommerce! Perfect!

But, why can't I create a new product?

my new product:

```
var data = {
    product: {
      title: 'Premium Quality',
      type: 'simple',
      regular_price: '21.99',
      description: 'Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.',
      short_description: 'Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.',
      categories: [
        9,
        14
      ],
      images: [
        {
          src: 'http://www.adpic.de/data/picture/detail/Wasserflasche_74756.jpg',
          position: 0
        },
        {
          src: 'http://www.adpic.de/data/picture/detail/Wasserflasche_74756.jpg',
          position: 1
        }
      ]
    }
  };
```

my ajax `POST` request:

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: woocommerceURLcreateProduct,
  data: $.param(data)
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
    console.log( "Data Saved: " );
    console.log( msg );
  });
```

**I get the error:**

```
{code: "woocommerce_api_missing_callback_param", message: "Missing Parameter data"}
```

Source:

http://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/v2.html?javascript#create-a-product

Comment: From the page you linked, create is a `POST`, not a `GET`.

Comment: True, thx. I changed it. Now its saying:  {
  "errors": [
    {
      "code": "woocommerce_api_missing_callback_param",
      "message": "Missing parameter data"
    }
  ]
}

Answer (score 1):

According to the [jQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/), `jQuery.param(...)` takes your object and serializes it into a string, typically used for transferring data via `GET`.

According to [WooCommerce Docs](https://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#create-a-product), your requests should be sent as a JSON string.

Replace `data: $.param(data)` with `data: data`, jQuery's ajax allows you to pass an object as your data, and it will do all the hard work of stringifying it into a JSON string for the endpoint.

Don't forget to set your dataType to `json` in your ajax call, so jQuery can parse WooCommerce's JSON response.

Comment: thx Sean, I'd tried that already, but get the same error 

`$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: woocommerceURLcreateProduct,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: "JSON"
});`